# Особенности использования select в LINQ

Tags: c#, windows, linq

Объясните, пожалуйста,

1. cust это ключевое слово и название переменной?
2. и select cust это надо понимать как взять значение удовлетворяющее условиям выше?

```
var query = from cust in customers.AsEnumerable()
            where cust.Field<int>("CustomerNo") == 1 || cust.Field<int>("CustomerNo") == 2
            orderby cust["CustomerNo"] descending
            select cust;
```

Comment: 1) переменной 2) да

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы разобраться с синтаксисом надо обратиться к [справке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause).

> В предложении `from` указывается следующее:
>
> 1. источник данных, на котором будет выполняться запрос (`dataSource`)
> 2. локальная переменная, соответствующая отдельному элементу исходной последовательности (`rangeVariable`)

В общем виде синтаксис такой:

```
from rangeVariable in dataSource
```

Список ключевых слов можно так же найти на странице [справки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/query-keywords)

---

Предложение [`select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/select-clause) описывает какой результат будет при выполнении запроса. Результат основывается на результате всех предыдущих предложений, а так же на результате выражений непосредственно в самом предложении `select`.